# Generic function type

Tags: typescript

I can create a function type like this:

```
type read = (name: string) => void;

const test:read = (value: string) => {
  console.log(value);
}
```

How would the implementation of `test` look like, if I would change `read` like this:

```
type read<T> = (name:T) => void;
```

This does not work:

```
const test<T>:read<T> = (value: T) => {
  console.log(value);
}
```

[TS Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAThCGATAPAFQHxQLxQBQDt4BbCALlQEptMA3AewEtEBuAKFYGM78BnYKYBD5p0pOEhHY8hEqSiVqUAN6soa9V150ANhAB02ugHMCxCBTYBfIA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New Answer**

Generic named functions use the following syntax:

```
function test<T>(name: T) : void {
    console.log(name);
}
```

And the syntax for assigning the function to a constant:

```
const test = <T>(name: T) : void => {};
```

[Typescript Playground Example](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAThCGATAPAFQHxQLxQBQDt4BbCALlQEptMA3AewEtEBuAKFYDMBXfAY2AZ18UYBADOwAGI9+g-GnQFiZKJSiko9JlADerKAai8hYugBsIAOjN0A5kpIU2AX3bH8EkeOABhE8Hh8YGwoBQcVNQ0tRGpdZ2YgA)

[More reading on generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

**Old Answer**

This is what you want:

```
type read<T> = (name:T) => void;

const test : read<string> = (name) => {
      console.log(name);
}
```

Then to extend, if you want one function to take multiple types:

```
const testFlex : read<string|number> = (name) => {
    console.log(name);
}

testFlex('a');
testFlex(1);
```

And separate functions for separate types:

```
const testString : read<string> = (name) => {
    console.log(name);
}

const testNumber : read<number> = (name) => {
    console.log(name);
}

testString('a');
testNumber(1);
```

[Typescript Playground Example](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAThCGATAPAFQHxQLxQBQDt4BbCALlQEptMA3AewEtEBuAKFYGM78BnYKYBD4AxADYQAHlFKwEKPjAb4A5gB98AVyIAjCDEw4CxCFSyYA3qyjWoXXnXEA6UXWVGSFNgF92gkeIlcAHJ4IM9WP2AxSVwARnDObj4BIWAAZWBFFWlZJGQFJWUDPEIPaihLG1skhwhnV3cTb3Y7ZMiAOS1dGBy4PM0dPWLG0wsrG1ba+rdSptYfCNSMrLcQsLYOrr048KA)

Comment: No, I want to create a named generic function which matches the signature of `read<T>`.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler I have updated the answer to match your feedback